# redirect to same page after submit

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to submit a form when a file select is changed in my form and be able to redirect to same page.

ie: I have this url: http://localhost:3000/worker_steps/basic_info. after dropdown changed, I want the form be submitted and redirect again to http://localhost:3000/worker_steps/basic_info.

I have this code in html:

```
<form class="simple_form form-horizontal" novalidate="novalidate" id="edit_user_385" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/worker_steps/basic_info" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post">
<input class="file optional" name="user[picture]" id="user_picture" type="file">  //this is th e dropdown select input
```

and in my jquery, I have this atm:

```
$("#user_picture").change(function(){
//window.location = "/worker_steps/basic_info";
$(this).closest("form").submit();    
});
```

Comment: Are you getting any error or what?

Answer (score 2):

I would just use this:

```
window.location.replace(window.location.href);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use header in

```
worker_steps/basic_info
```

file,
So put the below line at the end of the file,

```
header('location:the_current_page.html');
exit();
```